# Maven Project Build Exception

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

Trying to setup a sample Spring application using tutorial:

http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/spring-3-mvc-project-from-scratch/creating-a-project-layout

but on Page 4 of this tutrial, Maven is throwing this exception. Any pointers on to how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not able to resolve `maven-resources-plugin`, configure your pom.xml to use external public repository which has this plugin

```
 <project>
  .
  .
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  .
  .
 <project>
```